# Formik: How to set initial values for fieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui, formik

I am using Formik FieldArray in a Form Each row has 3 dropdowns. I'm not sure how to set the initial values in the dropdowns. For example, if I have the array

```
[
    {
        mainField: "one",
        operation: "one",
        value: ["one"]
    },
    {
        mainField: "two",
        operation: "two",
        value: ["two","2"]
    },
    {
        mainField: "three",
        operation: "three",
        value: ["3"]
    }
]
```

then, I want the Form to be loaded with these values in 3 rows initially.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Dropdown, Form, Grid, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Formik, FieldArray } from "formik";
import "./styles.css";

const mainField = [
  { key: "fruit", text: "fruit", value: "fruit" },
  { key: "color", text: "color", value: "color" },
  { key: "taste", text: "taste", value: "taste" }
];

const operation = [
  { key: "is ", text: "is ", value: "is " },
  { key: "is not ", text: "is not ", value: "is not " }
];
const options = [
  { key: "apple", text: "apple", value: "apple" },
  { key: "yellow", text: "yellow", value: "yellow" },
  { key: "sweet", text: "sweet", value: "sweet" }
];

const initialValues = [
  {
      mainField: "one",
      operation: "one",
      value: ["one"]
  },
  {
      mainField: "two",
      operation: "two",
      value: ["two","2"]
  },
  {
      mainField: "three",
      operation: "three",
      value: ["3"]
  }
]


const DropDownWithHooks = () => {
  const [dropDownOptions, setDropDownOptions] = useState(options);

  const handleAddition = (e, { value }) => {
    setDropDownOptions((prevOptions) => [
      { text: value, value },
      ...prevOptions
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ rows: initialValues }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        // transform the rows to add the condition key for each row object
        const output = values.rows.map((row, index) => {
          if (index === 0) {
            return { ...row, condition: "if" };
          } else {
            return { ...row, condition: "and" };
          }
        });

        console.log(output);
      }}
    >
      {({ handleSubmit, values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={"rulesetForm"}>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
          <FieldArray
            name="rows"
            render={({ push, remove }) => {
              return (
                values.rows.length > 0 &&
                values.rows.map((row, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Grid key={`mainfield-operation-value-${index}`}>
                      <Grid.Row className={"rulesetGrid fluid"}>
                        {index === 0 ? (
                          <p className="condition"> If</p>
                        ) : (
                          <p className="condition"> And</p>
                        )}

                        <Dropdown
                          name={`rows.${index}.mainField`}
                          className={"dropdown fieldDropdown"}
                          widths={2}
                          placeholder="Fruit"
                          fluid
                          selection
                          options={mainField}
                          value={row.mainField}
                          onChange={(e, { value }) =>
                            setFieldValue(`rows.${index}.mainField`, value)
                          }
                        />

                        <Dropdown
                          name={`rows.${index}.operation`}
                          className={"dropdown operationDropdown"}
                          widths={2}
                          placeholder="Operation"
                          fluid
                          selection
                          options={operation}
                          value={row.operation}
                          onChange={(e, { value }) =>
                            setFieldValue(`rows.${index}.operation`, value)
                          }
                        />
                        <Dropdown
                          name={`rows.${index}.value`}
                          className={"dropdown valueDropdown"}
                          widths={1}
                          placeholder="Value"
                          fluid
                          search
                          allowAdditions
                          selection
                          multiple
                          options={dropDownOptions}
                          value={row.value}
                          onAddItem={handleAddition}
                          onChange={(e, { value }) =>
                            setFieldValue(`rows.${index}.value`, value)
                          }
                        />

                        {values.rows.length - 1 === index && (
                          <Icon
                            className={"  plus icon plusIcon"}
                            onClick={() => push(initialValues)}
                          />
                        )}
                        {values.rows.length !== 1 && (
                          <Icon
                            className={"minus crossIcon"}
                            onClick={() => remove(index)}
                          />
                        )}
                      </Grid.Row>
                    </Grid>
                  );
                })
              );
            }}
          />
          <div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
              <Button
                floated="right"
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
                primary={true}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default DropDownWithHooks;
```

With this code, I am not getting these values initially in the dropdowns. Please help Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-ls1ox?file=/example.js) here

Comment: Were you able to solve it?